# Firebase.database is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple login page with JavaScript and Firebase except I keep coming across this error

```
Untaught TypeError: Firebase.database is not a function
```

After searching the internet and trying everything, I still have no results. The problem persists on the signUp page when signing up for an account.

I have got to the point where the account will be made and can be seen, but in my real-time database in Firebase console nothing shows up where I am trying to write in the database that I want the inputted ‘firstName’ there.

I have attached the code below:

—Login
https://jsfiddle.net/jLf5q34o/

—SignUp
https://jsfiddle.net/dq8o1tLv/

—I also have the full project online at:
https://inputgeo.com/experiment/

I would appreciate any help from anyone. If I haven’t explained this very well please let me know and I will try to explain this again.

Comment: You're including firebase-auth, storage etc but not firebase-database.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the script requests, you haven't imported `firebase-database`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```